# Email case capture in netsuite

Tags: email, case, netsuite

I want to create case through email in Netsuite. I test it by sending a email to email address from Setup -> Support -> Support preferences. But it does not create a case. I have also asked Netsuite Support centre but did not get any reply.

Please suggest how to configure email case capture.

Comment: Did you first set up Setup -> Company -> Enable Features and enable "Email Case Capture" under the CRM tab?

Comment: Yes I have already do that. But still did not work.

Comment: How do you know it didn't create a case? Do you have any support case scripts running that might have thrown an error in a before Submit user event? When you look at the list of support cases is it filtered for a particular user?

Comment: When I go to Lists-> Support -> Cases, it does not show the case that I have sent through email.